# Use grails plugin datasource

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'm using Grails 2.2.4 to build a plugin. The plugin is an access manager and need to access some datasources (more than one). As the Grails manual specify in [Providing Basic Artefacts](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.4/guide/plugins.html#providingBasicArtefacts), the ***DataSource.groovy*** is not bundled with the plugin.

Is there a way to "copy" the datasources defined on the plugin DataSource.groovy file to the application's DataSource.groovy file that uses the plugin?

I really don't want to manually define the plugin datasources on every application that uses the plugin.

============

Full stacktrace (requested in comments)

```
2013-12-11 11:39:33,055 ERROR org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsConte
xtLoader - Error initializing the application: groovy.lang.MissingMethodExceptio
n: No signature of method: portal.Aplicacao.methodMissing() is applicable for ar
gument types: () values: []
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: groovy.lang.MissingMetho
dException: No signature of method: portal.Aplicacao.methodMissing() is applicab
le for argument types: () values: []
        at grails.util.Environment.evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock(Environment.
java:308)
        at grails.util.Environment.executeForEnvironment(Environment.java:301)
        at grails.util.Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment(Environment.java
:277)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExec
utor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor     .java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: portal.Ap
licacao.methodMissing() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
        at portal.PortalService.criaAplicacaoNoPortal(PortalService.groovy:233)
        at BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:16)
        ... 8 more
```

Comment: Hmmm... how are you running this code? Are you running the plugin or including it in an application?

Comment: including the plugin in an application. The exception jumps off when the application is running the BootStrap, so I think that the platform-core-plugin neither my plugin were invoked yet, am I right?

Comment: Hmmm, I don't think so, I did the same sort of stuff weeks ago, using the plugin entities in an application BootStrap and it worked alright. I don't recall having this exact problem, but I remember having to surround the code with `PluginEntity.withTransaction { /* code using plugin entities here */ }`.

Comment: My BootStrap calls a service defined in the plugin, the service is the one that use the entity. So no way to call withTransaction neither other entity staff to do the trick

Comment: You're right. Can you try opening `grails console` in the application, and see if the plugin entities appear in `grailsApplication.domainClasses`?

Comment: With grails console the config works, but with run-app the configuration was not loaded (I used a lot of printlns to discovery this). Well, at the end, I discovered that other plugin messed up the start of the application. Now the app is running. Thanks for the support.

Comment: Glad you worked it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [platform-core plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/platform-core), and then define the dataSources as application config in the `doWithConfig` section of your plugin, like so:

```
def doWithConfig = { config ->

    // ...

    application {
        Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment {
            development {
                    dataSource_myDatasource {
                        dbCreate = "create-drop"
                        url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
                        // other datasource configuration here...
                    }
                }
            }
            test {
                    dataSource_myDatasource {
                        // test datasource
                        dbCreate = "create-drop"
                        url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
                        // ...
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this is not part of Grails itself, but a feature of the platform-config plugin

Comment: @BurtBeckwith Thank you, I had forgotten about that! I'm fixing the answer right now.

Comment: I have used the suggested strategy, but I got a MissingMethodException on the plugin entities. Do you know why GORM doesn't work?

Comment: Hmmm, can you post the stacktrace? Did you install the platform-core plugin? Also, make sure you use `loadBefore = ['dataSource']` in the plugin configuration.

Comment: Full stacktrace at the end of question